# List items in arraylist Java

Tags: java, android

I have a class like this

```
import java.io.Serializable;

class Message implements Serializable
{
    public String message, sender;
    public Message (String msg, String from)
    {
        // check here that msg and from are not null. If so, use a default value or throw an NullPointerException
        message = msg;
        sender = from;
    }
    // Just a utility method for printing out the Message to System.out
    public String toString () { return sender+": "+message; }
}
```

I want to list items in this variable.

```
ArrayList<Message> extractedMessages = (ArrayList<Message>)getArguments().getSerializable("messages");
```

When I run this code:

```
System.out.println(extractedMessages);
```

Output is:

```
[user01:hi,user02:hi,user01:test]
```

When I run this code

```
extractedMessages.get(0);
```

I am getting java null pointer exception.

I want to list each message like this consept

```
sender:message
sender:message
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Try: System.out.println( extractedMessages.get(0).toString() );

Comment: As per the `return sender+": "+message;` there must be a single spcae after `:` but it's not there `user01:hi`. You are getting from another list, not the printed one.

Comment: Not worked,still same error.

Comment: share complete code for fast resolution.

Comment: Try extractedMessages.get("user01");

Comment: @Paritosh not worked.Also it's not working too extractedMessages.size()

Comment: This is fragment code:http://pastebin.com/uAthuVze This is main activity:http://pastebin.com/wXWLXx6G